# How to slowly move a slider with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webautomation

I'm trying to move a slider slowly and smoothly with selenium but haven't found a way to do so.

[https://jqueryui.com/slider/](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

ive found 2 methods of doing it, the first one moves it slow but not smoothly and the second one i was trying to use drag and drop to do it but it just moves it instantly.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import math

options = Options()
options.add_argument('log-level=3')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="/Users/andy_/Desktop/driver/chromedriver2.exe") # chrome_options=driver_options +
os.system('cls')


driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/slider/")

def move_slider(slider, offset):
    number = offset/20
    frac, whole = math.modf(number)
    dec = frac*20
    ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(slider).perform()
    for i in range(20):
        ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(number, 0).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(dec, 0).perform()
    ActionChains(driver).release().perform()

def move_slider2(slider, offset):
    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(slider, 80, 0).perform()

sleep(1)

driver.switch_to.frame(0)
slider2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default']")
    
move_slider2(slider2, 80)
```

Comment: And where are your efforts?

Answer (score 1):

[*`drag_and_drop_by_offset(source, xoffset, yoffset)`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.drag_and_drop_by_offset) holds down the left mouse button on the source element, then moves to the target offset and releases the mouse button.

---

### Solution

To slowly move the slider on the [webpage](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) you can use the following solution:

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get('https://jqueryui.com/slider/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src='/resources/demos/slider/default.html']")))
  slider = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#slider > span")))
  ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop_by_offset(slider, 80, 0).perform()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: slider]

Comment: This didnt work for me.

Comment: @Andh Just copy & paste the entire code block. Don't leave out any line. The solution is well tested and it works perfecto.